# Export HTML Table to PDF using mPDF

Tags: php, html-table, mpdf

I have am using mPDF to convert and export the data from my html table to PDF. The button on my table works and the data can be exported. However the code only passes [one variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrTbt.png). I want to pass all the variables. I cannot pinpoint what else is missing in my code. Can anyone help me?

Here is the link button from index.php:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
         echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td>" .$row['eventvolunteerID'] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" .$row['eventTitle'] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" .$row['rollno'] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" .$row['eventDate'] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" .$row['eventTime'] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" .$row['eventLimit'] .  "</td>";
         echo "<td><a href='makepdf2.php?eventvolunteerID=".$row['eventvolunteerID']."'>Create PDF</a></td>";
         echo "</tr>";
```

Here is my code for processing the PDF (makepdf2.php):

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
if(isset($_GET['eventvolunteerID'])) {

$eventvolunteerID = $_GET['eventvolunteerID'];
$eventTitle = $_GET['eventTitle'];
$rollno = $_GET['rollno'];
$eventDate = $_GET['eventDate'];
$eventTime = $_GET['eventTime'];
$eventLimit = $_GET['eventLimit'];

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

$data = '';
$data .= '<strong>Event Volunteer ID:</strong> ' . $eventvolunteerID . '<br/>';
$data .= '<strong>Event Title:</strong> ' . $eventTitle . '<br/>';
$data .= '<strong>Roll no.:</strong> ' . $rollno . '<br/>';
$data .= '<strong>Event Date:</strong> ' . $eventDate . '<br/>';
$data .= '<strong>Event Time:</strong> ' . $eventTime . '<br/>';
$data .= '<strong>Event Limit:</strong> ' . $eventLimit . '<br/>';
$mpdf->WriteHTML($data);
$mpdf->Output('myfile.pdf', 'D');
}
?>
```

Please do help. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong (no expert in PHP) but in your link you only pass the `eventvolunteerID` to your makepdf2.php file... Inside the file you `_GET` some other variables, where should these come from?

Answer (score 2):

You have added button to each row of table and when it's clicked you pass the id of data that row has and hence you export only single row.

You suppose to do add button on Top of HTML table. By clicking it you supposed to pass all the variable values to makepdf2.php and write the same Database query to fetch all the data.

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

if(isset($_GET['checkyouraction'])) {

    // Write your Database query here to get $result

    $data = '';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $data .= '<strong>Event Volunteer ID:</strong> ' . $row['eventvolunteerID'] . '<br/>';
        $data .= '<strong>Event Title:</strong> ' . $row['eventTitle'] . '<br/>';
        $data .= '<strong>Roll no.:</strong> ' . $row['rollno'] . '<br/>';
        $data .= '<strong>Event Date:</strong> ' . $row['eventDate'] . '<br/>';
        $data .= '<strong>Event Time:</strong> ' . $row['eventTime'] . '<br/>';
        $data .= '<strong>Event Limit:</strong> ' . $row['eventLimit'] . '<br/>';
    }

    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

    $mpdf->WriteHTML($data);
    $mpdf->Output('myfile.pdf', 'D');
}
```

Above code generate you all the records. If you wish to display data in tabular format you can use same HTML table/tr/td structure.